# Is The Text of the Legend Lore Spell a Reference To Something?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

The text of the Legend Lore spell (PHB p. 246–7) gives examples of what kind of lore a player might learn, and refers to specific characters and locations. Are these examples made from whole cloth, or are they references to events in D&D books or other material?

Comment: The d20 SRD doesn't have any of the examples I'm referring to.  please don't edit the link.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that difference -- but the page you're on is reproducing a lot of non-SRD illegitimately, and we make a point of not linking to sites and pages doing that. You should probably just quote the paragraph or two with those examples and drop the link. Separately, which edition is this from - 3.5e, right?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. The 5e PHB has an abridged version of the examples, but I don't know what edition the quoted text is from.

Comment: We shouldn't be quoting text that we won't link to either. Providing a page number so people who properly own the book can read it themselves is sufficient.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie We can quote a couple of paragraphs from the book under fair use for the purpose of examination. Linking to a page describing the entire spell and a dozen others is excessive and decisively not fair use. Not linking to something _doesn't_ follow to whether or not we'd quote a book. However, on the separate matter of only needing a page number: I agree that's all that necessary and that those without the book _can_ go without knowing what's going on.

Answer (score 4):

- Son or Daughter of Stone is probably a reference to [dwarfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwarf_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)) being Races of Stone
- [Moradin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moradin) is definitely D&D.
- [Rudnogg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b8u9KiFRoRI) is a Balkan band - they are definitely on my playlist when I am looking for that East European feel to my D&D campaign.
- Couldn't find Vanashon but [Vinashin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinashin) is a Vietnamese state owned shipbuilder; whether named for a paladin in a classic South-East Asian campaign I couldn't say.
- [Forbidden Mountain](http://evil.wikia.com/wiki/Forbidden_Mountain) is where [Maleficent's](http://villains.wikia.com/wiki/Maleficent_%28Disney%29) castle is - just try and tell me she wasn't the model for every evil sorceress in D&D; turning Vietnamese shipbuilders to stone is right up her ally too.
- [Ryth](http://infinityblade.wikia.com/wiki/Ryth) is a Deathless found in Infinity Blade II and III; these post-date D&D but the complex interrelationship between computer and desktop RPGs may mean that time may not be linear in this respect. As evidence, I point out that there are [at least 7 people](http://www.babycenter.com/babyNameAllPops.htm?babyNameId=724915) in the world named Ryth and that they were named *before* the video games but *after* D&D were released. Spooky, isn't it?

Comment: So basically, no?