# How much information should the GM reveal with a Legend Lore spell?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, artifacts

The PCs decided they want a minor artifact (deck of many things) and decided to cast a Legend Lore to get information about it. They intend to barter, but if it stands within the grasp of an evil NPC, to take it by force.

How much information should I give them? How tough should I make their quest?

Obs.: I have no restraints about them getting the deck or suffering the consequences. Actually it is a very fun item and I would have no problem in adequating the campaign. I can already predict lots of laughs from misfortunes or satisfaction from fortunes.

Obs. 2: the group is quite accomplished and the best PCs (who haven't died yet) are level 16 right now.

Comment: "Actually it is a very fun item and I would have no problem in adequating the campaign." - What do you mean by "adequating" here?

Comment: I mean that if someone gets nerfed or overpowered because of the deck it has no effect in the campaign. It's not necessarily level dependent.

Comment: @Daniel Did you mean to write "adapting" instead of "adequating"? This is likely a language issue, as "adequating" is not really a word that is ever used in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## It's really up to you the DM

This question is opinion based I believe because the spell has a good description but it is left vague on purpose so it's hard to come with a satisfactory answer. Plus **it depends how much info they have on the artifact as stated in the spell description**.

**However** there's a part in the 3.5 version of the spell that gives examples of what kind of lore a player might learn that I discovered  that might help you in this question: [Is The Text of the Legend Lore Spell a Reference To Something?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67235/51979)

From Legend Lore (PHB p. 246–7  3.5 edition)

> (...)Examples of legend lore results include
> the following. **A divination about a mysterious magic
> axe you have at hand**: “Woe to the evildoer
> whose hand touches the axe, for even the
> haft chops the hand of the evil ones. Only
> a true Son or Daughter of Stone, one who
> loves Moradin and whom Moradin loves,
> may awaken the true powers of the axe,
> and only with the sacred word ‘Rudnogg’ on
> the lips.”
> **A divination about a legendary paladin
> about whom you know many details**:
> “Vanashon has been denied the glory of
> death and the duty of life. He waits patiently
> beneath the Forbidden Mountain.”
> (The paladin has been turned to stone in
> the caverns under the mountain.)
> **A divination about ancient ruins about
> which you have only a passing reference in
> a partially damaged tome**: “The sorcerer
> who called herself Ryth built a library
> without words and a temple without gods.
> Those tho read and those who pray tore it
> down in a night and a day.” (These clues
> may be enough for you to find out more
> and get details you need to cast a better
> legend lore.) (...)